# Property 'hash' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: jquery, angular, angular7

I am working with angular7. I need to make single page website, so i have provide id name of the section in the menu link. So when you click the link it will take you to the respective section in the page. I used following jQuery code for that.

```
    $(".navbar .nav-link").on('click', function(event) {
        var hash = this.hash;
        if (this.hash !== "") {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 1000, function(){
                window.location.hash = hash;
            });
        } 
    });
```

Its working in normal html format, but its shows the following error when i moved in to the angular frame work.

> src/app/app.component.ts(20,13): error TS2339: Property 'hash' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

Comment: Use arrow function to capture the correct `this`

Comment: change the event function to arrow function

Comment: this.hash; is this component property ?

Comment: yes it is buddy.

Comment: okay i will try to use arrow function function instead of event function.

Comment: did this work for you @VetrivelPandiyarajan? it didn't for me